# Responsive horizontal menu needs overflow hidden but how?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a multi-level horizontal menu with unknown number of top level and sub level menus. I want to display this menu as a single line and display as many as the display width will allow. I'm planning to then put all the menu items in a modal dialogue box which the icon is right justified in the menu.

I'm using zurb foundation 5 and I need the menu to cater for different screen widths but I'm 99.9% certain this is a css problem, not foundation. (ie I don't want to code for medium/large/xlarge)

My problem is that I'm having trouble limiting the menu to a single level. It spills/overflows onto subsequent lines but if I specify a height and overflow:hidden, it then breaks the multi-level sub levels of the menu.

I've created a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gavtwtd/4tkpoL74/6/
but please note you may have to widen the result pane to see the problem.

Ah, I must accompany jsfiddle with my code, so here's some code:

```
<div class="sticky">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="right">
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">&#9776;</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="left" style="width:90%;">
                <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub menu 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub menu 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 99</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>full menu here  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></div>
```

Comment: That is normal behavior of css, once your div is `overflow: hidden`, it's children can't pop out of this div. Here is a solution using a mix of css and javascript: http://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: I was afraid of that. Ok thanks for the pointer.